# Mongoose and Typescript Model requirement function

Tags: typescript, mongoose, model, this

I am creating a model in typescript in mongoose and I would like to use a required function, however unlike normal javascript, I cannot use the 'this' operator as typescript doesn't recognize the scope.  I would like to access the value of another one of the objects properties, but I am not sure how to do it.  Here is what I am looking for:

```
export interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
  name: string; 
  somethingElse?: number; 
};

export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type:String, required: true},
  somethingElse: required: function() {
     // use this.name here ......
  }

});

const User = mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
```

In this example, I would like to be able to access 'this.name', but typescript doesn't understand this method.  What is the proper way to do this in typescript?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if it's the best way to do it, but have you tried this ?

```
export interface IUser extends mongoose.Document {
  name: string; 
  somethingElse?: number; 
};

export const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type:String, required: true},
});

UserSchema.obj.somethingElse.required = function () {
  // use this.name here ......
}

const User = mongoose.model<IUser>('User', UserSchema);
```