# Get required function's this value in mongoose using typescript

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I'm trying to validate a property's value that is it an whole number or not. I need to get the fields value in the require prop's function like below:

```
preview: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
            required: validateTheNumber(this) 
         }
```

But I got an error at `required` field. It says `Argument of type 'typeof globalThis' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.ts(2345)`

I just started to typescript and I'm migrating my JS project into TS. I simply want to get the `preview`'s value in the `validateTheNumber` function.

I came across with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59615773/mongoose-and-typescript-model-requirement-function) question but it wouldn't help either.

Comment: One would need to see 'validateTheNumber' to answer this question.

Comment: It's just a function that takes a param. Nothing crazy in it!
Edit: Okay, this is the function:
`function validateTheNumber(value) { return value <= 0 ? 0 : value };`

Comment: This works just fine with pure JS BTW

Comment: If that's the function, 'value' is implicitly any and therefore this should work. Are you sure that's the function you're using? You can try `function validateTheNumber(value: any) { return value <= 0 ? 0 : value }`, maybe that will work. However, the error indicates the function is typed like this: `function validateTheNumber(value: number)`, which is illegal because you don't know if `this` is a `number`